# C# Input Validation Check for positive numbers

Tags: c#, string, decimal, validation, tryparse

I am learning C# and stuck on a problem where I have to check if the user input a VALID currency amount. i.e. no alphabetical character and no negative numbers.

So far I have everything in the program complete EXCEPT that particular input validation.

to convert the input to numeric values i have:
originalRate = Double.Parse(txtValue.Text);

then below that i am stumped, i have been messing around with:
bool isValid = Double.TryParse(txtValue.Text, );

The common <s>compiler</s> runtime error I get while messing around is **Input string was not in a correct format**. Which i know it is, that is what I am checking for.
I know this is super basic stuff (this is my first C# class). I have searched around on stack overflow and none of the similar solutions make much sense to me at this point. I have been told to use the **TryParse** method of the **decimal** class, however feel as though I am using it wrong and incomplete.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not a compiler error btw. It's a runtime error since it occurs at runtime and not at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you use [`double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx)

```
double d;
bool isValid = Double.TryParse(txtValue.Text, out d);
```

the MDSN page has some examples.

To parse currency string, you could use the second overload of [`double.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx)

and try something like

```
double d;
bool isValid = double.TryParse(txtValue.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), out d);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double result;

if (double.TryParse(txtValue.text, out result))
{
    // The user typed a valid number.
    // Do something with it (it’s in “result”).
}
else
{
    // The user typed something invalid.
    MessageBox.Show("Please type in a number.");
}
```